# Can I get the locations of all members of a facebook group if I am the admin?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook group for ex-students that finished my university course. We plan on getting all of the user's locations and plot that data into a world map, so we can promote the course.

Will I be able to get user's locations as a group administrator, even if I'm not a direct friend of some of the members?

If this is not possible what do you recommend? An app that asks for permissions upon entering would solve this, but it really makes sense to keep this as a group for the user interaction.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Of course not. Facebook _only_ gives away the location for the current user of an _app_, and only if that user gives the app permission to read that information before.

Comment: That's what I thought, I wanted to confirm it. Is app my only way to go?

Comment: Unless you want to visit their profile yourself and look for that info from those who made it publicly available: Yes.

Comment: if you want to transcript the comment to an answer, I'll mark it as correct. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will I be able to get user's locations as a group administrator, even if I'm not a direct friend of some of the members?

Of course not. (And no, even if you are their friend, you will at most get it by visiting each of their profiles directly.)

Outside of the context of browsing facebook.com directly, Facebook *only* gives away the location for the current user of an app, and only if that user gives the app permission to read that information before.

Whether or not the user has marked this info as “public” does not matter – this setting only applies to what other users get to see when they browse facebook.com, *not* what an app is able to access.